# Is there any way to make the time stop counting up in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In my excel sheet I have the following code:

```
 =IF(ISERROR(MATCH(D2,'Sheet 2'!A:A,0)),"",NOW())
```

This basically checks to see if the value in D2 matches any values in column A:A in sheet 2, and then populates the cell with a date and time with NOW().

My problem is the date and time is counting up because I am using the NOW() function whereas what I need is the date to, in a way, take a snapshot of the date or freeze the date. This table I am creating is acting like a log so I need the date to stay as it is when it is put into the cell.

Any help with this is much appreciated.

Comment: Try replacing the `NOW()` with `TODAY()`, this will give you only the date, without the time.

Comment: @ShaiRado Thanks for your reply, but this will count the date up too, I need both the date and the time to stay as they are.

Comment: Could you just copy and paste the value?

Comment: @TomSharpe I could but it will defeat the object of having a log running in the background. I basically have a button that saves the print area on my sheet as a PDF file and we save 1000's of PDFs from this sheet so my aim was to log each and every PDF we save with its details and the date and time it was created.

Answer (score 1):

You could have this automatically run, if you paste it in the code behind your sheet (Where the range `theCells` is the column where the timestamps are going):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range

    ' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will
    ' cause an alert when they are changed.
    Set KeyCells = Range("theCells")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
           Is Nothing Then

        If Range(Target.Address).Value <> "" Then
            Range(Target.Address).Copy
            Range(Target.Address).PasteSpecial xlPasteVaues
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried to use this but I could not get it to work because I'm not too good at VBA but below I have fixed my problem

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I solved it, In my VBA I have the following code which pretty much creates a log file when my button is clicked, it takes various information in different cells and populates it in the next defined available row:

```
Sub copylog()
Dim LastRow As Long, ws As Worksheet
Dim wt As Worksheet

Set ws = Sheets("Create Log")
Set wt = Sheets("PDF Creation")
LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
 ws.Range("A" & LastRow).Value = wt.Range("N11").Value
 ws.Range("B" & LastRow).Value = wt.Range("N12").Value
 ws.Range("C" & LastRow).Value = wt.Range("N13").Value
 ws.Range("D" & LastRow).Value = wt.Range("N14").Value
 ws.Range("E" & LastRow).Value = wt.Range("N15").Value
 ws.Range("F" & LastRow).Value = wt.Range("N16").Value
 ws.Range("G" & LastRow).Value = wt.Range("AT19").Value
 ws.Range("H" & LastRow).Value = wt.Range("AT21").Value
 ws.Range("I" & LastRow).Value = wt.Range("AT23").Value
 ws.Range("J" & LastRow).Value = wt.Range("AT25").Value
 ws.Range("K" & LastRow).Value = wt.Range("AT27").Value
 ws.Range("L" & LastRow).Value = wt.Range("A2").Value
 ws.Range("M" & LastRow).Value = Environ("Username")
 End Sub
```

The code above will populate a table in the next available row, for example, the first line:

```
 ws.Range("A" & LastRow).Value = wt.Range("N11").Value
```

This will take the value that populates N11 in the PDF create sheet and populate the next available row in column A in the create log sheet (using copy and paste).

The line that has fixed my time problem is the line:

```
 ws.Range("L" & LastRow).Value = wt.Range("A2").Value
```

In cell A2, I have the NOW() function and the button copies and pastes it into the next available space in column L (copies and pastes as TEXT).